# What wrong in 'print_element' method ?

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

```
print("<&s &s>" &(element.tag,element.attrib))
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tag'

```
from lxml import html
import requests

def print_element(element):
    print("<&s &s>" &(element.tag,element.attrib))

r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_and_their_capitals_in_native_languages")

tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
s = tree.xpath('//table')
print_element(s)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The s you got is a list,so you should use the item in the list. And maybe you should change '&' to '%'.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

def print_element(element):
    print("<%s %s>" %(element.tag,element.attrib))

r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_and_their_capitals_in_native_languages")

tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
s = tree.xpath('//table')
print type(s)   # you will see this s is a list
for item in s:
    print_element(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `element` is a list of "elements" and not a single element.